# Get foreign key data based on shop id

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables: shop and menu.

**shop**

```
$table->id();
$table->string('name');
```

**menu**

```
$table->id();
$table->string('name');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('shop_id');
$table->foreign('shop_id')->references('id')->on('shop')->onDelete('cascade');
```

I need to print out menus name when you enter shop id (for example url /shop{id})

I have controller but i'm sure it's not the correct code.

**MeniuController**

```
public function menu($id)
{
    $men = shop::select('name')->where('id', $id)->get();
    return view('meniu', compact('men')); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller method:

```
public function menu($id)
{
   return view('menu', [
      'menus' => Menu::where('shop_id', $id)->get(),
   ]);
}
```

Blade template:

```
@foreach($menus as $menu)
   <div>{{ $menu->name }}</div>
@endforeach
```